# Convert decimal number double to hour, time, or difftime in R

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have a vector of doubles specifying hours in a day, such as the example given below. `6.50` would correspond to `06:30` in `hh:mm` format and so on.

```
ts <- c(6.50, 7.00, 7.25, 7.45, 8.00)
```

I would like to convert this to a date or time format. The solution that I could come up with involves striping the decimal places from the number and converting them to minutes, but this feels a bit "hacky", e.g.

```
library(lubridate)
hm(paste(floor(ts), (ts - floor(ts)) * 60, sep = ':'))
```

Surely there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(chron)

times(ts / 24)
## [1] 06:30:00 07:00:00 07:15:00 07:27:00 08:00:00
```

This would also work:

```
library(chron)
library(lubridate)

hms(times(ts/24))
## [1] "6H 30M 0S" "7H 0M 0S"  "7H 15M 0S" "7H 27M 0S" "8H 0M 0S"
```

Comment: This works well, thank you!
Surprised this isn't more simple with lubridate

Answer (score 1):

Sticking only with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
as.period(as.duration(days(x=1))*(ts/24))
# "6H 30M 0S" "7H 0M 0S"  "7H 15M 0S" "7H 27M 0S" "8H 0M 0S"
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a lubridate approach! I run into the following error: `Error in as.duration(days(x = 1)) : as.duration is not defined for class 'ordered'as.duration is not defined for class 'factor'`?

Comment: What do you get if you run? `days(x=1)` output=`[1] "1d 0H 0M 0S"` and `as.duration(days(x=1))` output=`[1] "86400s (~1 days)"`

Comment: Ah there we go! Namespace conflict with `chron`. This works: `as.period(as.duration(lubridate::days(x=1))*(ts/24))`. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sure thing...glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

```
> lubridate::hm(ts)
[1] "6H 50M 0S" "7H 0M 0S"  "7H 25M 0S" "7H 45M 0S" "8H 0M 0S"
```

Alternative to the request (what you already have in your question):

```
> paste(floor(ts), round((ts-floor(ts))*60), sep=":")
[1] "6:30" "7:0"  "7:15" "7:27" "8:0"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Please note that `6.5` is converted to `"6H 50M 0S"`, not `"6H 30M 0S"` as intended. So, unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, in that case other elements will update accordingly.